# redirect old email addresses to gmail address at MX record?

Tags: dns, gmail, mx-record

I've looked around online for the clearest answer to this, but am still not sure how to do it.

I have about 10 email addresses from a hosting account I've had for 15 years. I want to close down that hosting account, at the MX level send all email from ALL ADDRESSES to my ONE gmail email address.

My DNS info is with godaddy, and not the hosting service

Is this possible? If so what are the steps I need to take?

If/when this is done I can safely shut down the hosting account and still see what services out there are actively using these old addresses and change the email on file with them on my own time.

Comment: you need a paid service such as forwardmx.io  (I'm not affiliated and do not specifically recommend them)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but probably not as easy as you would hope. MX records don't really care about specific email addresses, their purpose is just to define a specific email servers as a destination for that domain's incoming emails.

With that in mind, you can easily point MX records to google servers, but than what? Google (gmail) email servers will simply not accept emails for some random domain unless they are specifically configured to accept them. For that, you will probably need a [business](https://www.google.com/gmail/about/for-work/) (payed) account.

Alternatively, you can look for similar (free?) service from some other email service provider.